# Three.js render a given object first

Tags: javascript, three.js

If I use Three.js canvas renderer, then is there any way, to render a given object before the other 3D objects? So can I modify somehow the object's rendering sequence in my scene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm, you can disable the renderer's autoclear and render in two passes.

```js
// on init
renderer.autoClear = false;

// on update
renderer.clear();
renderer.render( scene1, camera );
renderer.render( scene2, camera );
```

Comment: Is there another solution that doesn't require 2 scenes?